# R Base plot x-axis stretches Year by 0.2

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot point graph of 1 variable with 2 different years.

Data looks like this:

```
value Year
10.7  2022
2.9   2023
7.99  2022
0.41  2023
11    2022
0.5   2023
```

value column is numeric, Year - integer.

When I plot it using base plot, x axis becomes stretched and space between years is filled with 0.2 ticks.

[image: Graph]

How could I remove these ticks and leave only 2022 and 2023?

Using R base plot is mandatory, so no ggplot alternatives.

I've already tried making Year as.factor, but then it gives me box plot when point chart is needed:

[Graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MviXG.png)

Comment: Do `data$Year <- factor(data$Year)` before plotting if the table is called `data`

Comment: Then base plot gives box plot, but point chart is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
xtick<-unique(df$Year)
plot(df$Year, df$value, xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at=xtick, labels = xtick)
```

Output:

[image]

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(10.7, 2.9, 7.99, 0.41, 11, 0.5),
                 Year = c(2022, 2023, 2022, 2023, 2022, 2023))
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to reduce space between 2022 and 2023?

Comment: Hi @TomasDzedulionis, Try running this `dev.new(width=2, height=4)
` before the code.